# question about maven dependency

Tags: maven, dependencies

i loaded the maven project in eclipse then found sth wrong with pom.xml file, when i clicked the 'overview' tab(m2eclipse), it said:

```
Failed to read artifact descriptor for commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.2-SNAPSHOT
```

when i clicked the dependency hierarchy tab, it showed 'Project read error',  however i have no problem to  run 'mvn dependency:tree' from command line and can see there is a dependency on commons-logging:

```
commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
```

just don't understand where the commons-logging 1.1.2-SNAPSHOT comes from. any idea ?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eclipse by default does not use the same maven installation as your command line. Depending on your m2eclipse version it might use an embedded maven snaphsot (with strange behaviour). Check

```
eclipse -> Window -> Preferences -> Maven -> Installations
```

and add your external maven installation (prefer current version 3.0.3) to the list and use this as default.

Answer (score 1):

In order to determine where the dependency commons-logging comes from (even without the .pom editor and its dependency editor) open the console and execute the following command:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=commons-logging
```

This will show all dependencies of commons-logging.

I looked through the dependency tree, but did not find any reference to 1.1.2-SNAPSHOT.

Finally, adding the following dependency to my pom.xml solved the problem:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: If you are sure that the dependency is not used, excluding also solves the problem:
<exclusions>
   <exclusion>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
   </exclusion>
</exclusions>

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely coming into your project transitively. You can check the "Dependency Hierarchy" section of your pom editor in eclipse and see where it's coming from (search for commons-logging in the right top box). Also, I cannot see a 1.1.2-SNAPSHOT version of commons-logging on central so most likely someone has made a mistake in a dependency pom.

Comment: problem is when i clicked 'Dependency Hierarchy' sectionin the pom editor, it showed 'Project read error' in red color on the top and nothing showed in 'Dependency Hierarchy'.